# The join part uses OR that's why running long I'm trying to make it faster

Tags: sql-server

The join part uses OR that's why running  long I'm trying to make it faster

```
SELECT sc.clientid
            ,sc.dictionid
            ,sc.firstname 
            ,sc.lastname
            ,sc.DB
            ,sc.DOLS
            ,sc.dlnum
            ,Cons.Description AS ConS
            ,Conc.Description AS ConC
            ,'False' as Assigned
        FROM    [monitor].[uxref] xref 
            INNER JOIN [Monitor].[dbo].[seacc] sc
                    ON ( 
                            xref.regid = sc.[consid] 
                            OR xref.regid = sc.[concid] 
                        ) 
            LEFT JOIN [Monitor].[dbo].Reg Cons ON Cons.RegID = sc.ConsId
            LEFT JOIN [Monitor].[dbo].Reg Conc ON Conc.RegID = sc.ConcId
        WHERE xref.UserId =1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try a union of:

```
 SELECT sc.clientid
        ,sc.dictionid
        ,sc.firstname 
        ,sc.lastname
        ,sc.DB
        ,sc.DOLS
        ,sc.dlnum
        ,Cons.Description AS ConS
        ,Conc.Description AS ConC
        ,'False' as Assigned
    FROM    [monitor].[uxref] xref 
    JOIN [Monitor].[dbo].[seacc] sc
        ON xref.regid = sc.[consid] 
    LEFT JOIN [Monitor].[dbo].Reg Cons ON Cons.RegID = sc.ConsId
    LEFT JOIN [Monitor].[dbo].Reg Conc ON Conc.RegID = sc.ConcId
    WHERE xref.UserId =1000
```

and

```
 SELECT sc.clientid
        ,sc.dictionid
        ,sc.firstname 
        ,sc.lastname
        ,sc.DB
        ,sc.DOLS
        ,sc.dlnum
        ,Cons.Description AS ConS
        ,Conc.Description AS ConC
        ,'False' as Assigned
    FROM    [monitor].[uxref] xref 
    JOIN [Monitor].[dbo].[seacc] sc
        ON xref.regid = sc.[concid] 
    LEFT JOIN [Monitor].[dbo].Reg Cons ON Cons.RegID = sc.ConsId
    LEFT JOIN [Monitor].[dbo].Reg Conc ON Conc.RegID = sc.ConcId
    WHERE xref.UserId =1000
```

i.e.

```
 SELECT sc.clientid
        ,sc.dictionid
        ,sc.firstname 
        ,sc.lastname
        ,sc.DB
        ,sc.DOLS
        ,sc.dlnum
        ,Cons.Description AS ConS
        ,Conc.Description AS ConC
        ,'False' as Assigned
    FROM    [monitor].[uxref] xref 
    JOIN [Monitor].[dbo].[seacc] sc
        ON xref.regid = sc.[consid] 
    LEFT JOIN [Monitor].[dbo].Reg Cons ON Cons.RegID = sc.ConsId
    LEFT JOIN [Monitor].[dbo].Reg Conc ON Conc.RegID = sc.ConcId
    WHERE xref.UserId =1000
 UNION
 SELECT sc.clientid
        ,sc.dictionid
        ,sc.firstname 
        ,sc.lastname
        ,sc.DB
        ,sc.DOLS
        ,sc.dlnum
        ,Cons.Description AS ConS
        ,Conc.Description AS ConC
        ,'False' as Assigned
    FROM    [monitor].[uxref] xref 
    JOIN [Monitor].[dbo].[seacc] sc
        ON xref.regid = sc.[concid] 
    LEFT JOIN [Monitor].[dbo].Reg Cons ON Cons.RegID = sc.ConsId
    LEFT JOIN [Monitor].[dbo].Reg Conc ON Conc.RegID = sc.ConcId
    WHERE xref.UserId =1000
```